# Multiple boxplots on one plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Standard R plotting produces 30 boxplots in one plot when I use this code:

```
boxplot(Abundance[Quartile==1]~Year[Quartile==1],col="LightBlue",main="Quartile1 (Rare)")
```

I would like to produce something similar in ggplot2. So far i'm using this:

```
d1 = data.frame(x=data$Year[Quartile==1],y=data$Abundance[Quartile==1])
a <- ggplot(d1,aes(x,y))
a + geom_boxplot()
```

There are 30 years of data. In each year there are 145 species. In each year the 145 species are categorized into  quartiles of 1-4.

However, I'm only getting a single boxplot using this. Any idea how to get 30 boxplots (one for each year) along the x axes? Any help much appreciated.

There are 30 years of data. In each year there are 145 species. In each year the 145 species are categorized into  quartiles of 1-4.

Comment: Is the `Abundance` data your own private set? If so, please create a reproducible example, e.g. by using `iris` or `mtcars`

Comment: Taking a shoot in the dark, I guess you need to take a look at the melt function of the reshape2 package.

Comment: Also of interest when combining multiple ggplots is the gridExtra package and its grid.arrange function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What does `str(d1)` tell you about `x`? If numeric or integer, then that could be your problem. If `Year` is a factor, then you get a boxplot for each Year. As an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Some toy data
df <- data.frame(Year = rep(c(1:30), each=20), Value = rnorm(600))
str(df)
```

Note that `Year` is an integer variable

```
ggplot(df, aes(Year, Value)) + geom_boxplot()   # One boxplot

ggplot(df, aes(factor(Year), Value)) + geom_boxplot()   # 30 boxplots
```

Comment: Perfect! It was the simple 'factor' I was missing! Thanks for your help.